# Erro ao inserir dados no banco

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou fazendo um sistema em java com banco de dados postgresql para cadastro de clientes, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda para resolver meu problema.

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.psqlexception: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," 
> Posição:50
> ```

Classe Controle:

```
public class ControleCliente {

    ConexaoBD conex = new ConexaoBD();
    ModeloClientes modelo = new ModeloClientes();

    public void Salvar(ModeloClientes modelo){

        conex.conexao();

        try {

            PreparedStatement pat = conex.con.prepareStatement("insert into Clientes(nome_Cliente,telefone)values,codigo_Cliente(?,?,?)");
            pat.setString(1,modelo.getNome());
            pat.setInt(2,modelo.getTelefone());
            pat.setInt(3,modelo.getCodigo());
            pat.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cadastro Salvo com Sucesso!");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao inserir dados \nErro:!"+ex);
        }

        conex.desconecta();

    }

}
```

Classe Modelo:

```
package model;

public class ModeloClientes {

    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    private int telefone;

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(int telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

}
```

BOTÃO SALVAR:

```
private void jButtonGravarClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     

    modelo.setNome(jTextFieldNomeFantasia.getText());
    modelo.setTelefone(Integer.parseInt(jTxtClienteTelefone.getText()));

    controle.Salvar(modelo);

}
```

BANCO DE DADOS:

COLUNA CÓDIGO CLIENTE:

```
-- Column: public."Clientes"."codigo_Cliente"

-- ALTER TABLE public."Clientes" DROP COLUMN "codigo_Cliente";

ALTER TABLE public."Clientes"
ADD COLUMN "codigo_Cliente" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 
nextval('"Clientes_Código_seq"'::regclass);
```

COLUNA CÓDIGO CLIENTE:

```
-- Column: public."Clientes"."nome_Cliente"

-- ALTER TABLE public."Clientes" DROP COLUMN "nome_Cliente";

ALTER TABLE public."Clientes"
ADD COLUMN "nome_Cliente" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL;
```

COLUNA TELEFONE:

```
-- Column: public."Clientes".telefone

-- ALTER TABLE public."Clientes" DROP COLUMN telefone;

ALTER TABLE public."Clientes"
ADD COLUMN telefone integer;

COMMENT ON COLUMN public."Clientes".telefone
IS 'tel';
```

Comment: A sua query está errada: `INSERT INTO Clientes(nome_Cliente, telefone, codigo_Cliente) VALUES (?,?,?)`. Para evitar isso, passe o SQL na forma padrão dele, com letras maiúsculas. Corrija isso, que está relacionado ao erro que você postou. Caso ainda persista algum problema,atualize sua pergunta com as novidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `INSERT` está incorreto. A sintaxe correta seria:

```
"insert into Clientes(codigo_Cliente, nome_Cliente,telefone) values(?,?,?)"
```